# How to make bootable images of triple-boot OS on Mac OS

Tags: mac-osx, mac, partition, imaging

I would like to know the best practices or at least the method to do the following things that I am working on.

I have installed triple-boot OS (Windows 7, RHEL Linux and Mac OS 10.6) on iMac 7 using the [rEFit tool](http://refit.sourceforge.net/).

The goal I want to achieve is to make disk images of each of the partitions of the OS so that I can restore and install the images of them on other Mac machines.

I already made a Windows 7 image through a script that I wrote with help of [ntfsclone](http://edoceo.com/exemplar/ntfsclone-transfer-windows). I would like to know how to create a Linux image and a Mac OS image.

Will vanilla `dd` command like `dd if=/dev/sda3 of=~/linux.img` do the job? 
Mac OS partition can be imaged through the built-in disk utility as far as I know

Are the above methods workable to create a bootable image? Do I need to merge them somehow and if so, how? How can I include the EFI boot partition to make them bootable?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [DeployStudio](http://www.deploystudio.com/Home.html); I haven't tried this feature, but one of their example restore workflows splits the target disk in three partitions, restores a Mac OS X system (from a properly prepared .dmg image), a Windows system (IIRC from a WinClone image, not sure if it's compatible with ntfsclone), and a Linux system (from a .dd image).  It's free, and supports both local and network restores.  Setup can be a bit complex, so spend some time with the docs before plunging in.

Comment: Got to go with Deploy Studio. We use it in a college environment to support ~80 macs and it does support multi OS deployments and seems quite solid and reliable. Certainly a big improvement over netboot/netrestore which is what we were using beforehand.